# Combining xargs with cat and grep

Tags: bash, shell, command, cat, xargs

I want to take the output from a file and feed it in as arguments for a grep command on the same file that I want to execute against:

```
:~$ cat example
cat
dog
mouse
ant

:~$ cat example | xargs cat example | grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
cat: cat: No such file or directory
cat: dog: No such file or directory
cat: mouse: No such file or directory
cat: antTry 'grep --help' for more information.
: No such file or directory
```

In other words, expected commands would be:

```
cat example | grep cat
cat example | grep dog
cat example | grep mouse
cat example | grep ant
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the point? Supposing that there are no duplicates in the file and that the lines do not contain any regex metacharacters, the output that the pipeline you want would produce would be the same as the output of the initial `cat` command alone.

Comment: I have a file that contains hostnames. Each hostname has a "START" and a "FINISH" appended to it. ex: hostname1: START. Hostnames appear in randomized order so you will not see hostname1: START and the next line as hostname1: FINISH. It will most likely be mixed with others hostname22: START or hostname33: FINISH . etc.  I just want to first; extract the hostname part 'cat example | cut -d ':' -f 1' . second; feed the hostname as a grep argument when cat'ing the same file so the output will show in order: hostname1:START (\n) hostname1: FINISH (\n) hostname2: START (\n) hostname2: FINISH. etc.

Comment: The problem that you now describe is significantly different from what is presented in the question.  And it requires an approach significantly different from the solution attempt presented there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to feed the output of `cat example` to `xargs -I{}` like so, with `{}` being the argument placeholder:

```
cat example | xargs -n1 -I{} grep {} example
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether that answers what the OP is asking or not.  It they are open to reorganizing the command that much, then presumably they would consider abbreviating it all the way to `cat example`.  That's not 100% equivalent, but it would yield the same output in the example case.  If they're *not* up for that much reorganization, then they might not be up for as much as is suggested in this answer, either.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you, I agree. The OP should respond to your comment at the top and clarify.